# Using DateTime.AddHours from a static method does not product the desired result

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a helper class which among other things gets the current datetime. Because our server is 6 hours behind where ALL our customers are from I want to add 6 hours to the datetime. My public method is static and is as follows:

```
public static DateTime GetCurrentDate()
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        dt = dt.AddHours(6);
        return dt;
    }
```

For some reason if I `Response.Write` the datetime returned it has not added the 6 hours. If I do the above in an aspx.cs file and write out the result then it works. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at using DateTimeOffset and UTC

```
public static DateTime GetCurrentDate() 
{ 
   return DateTime.Now.AddHours(6); 
}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot, for some reason I had two similar methods in my class, one was just returning DateTime.Now(). Thanks for the answer anyways :)

Answer (score 4):

A better solution would be to avoid using `DateTime.Now` (which depends on the local time zone) and either use `DateTimeOffset` (which *explicitly*) refers to an instant in time or `DateTime.UtcNow` which at least returns a *universal* time instead of a local time. You're not *interested* in the local time of the server - you're interested in the current *instant* in time. By making your code express that instead of hard-coding the 6 hours, and by working with either `DateTimeOffset` or universal `DateTime` values everywhere, you're likely to end up with code which has a better chance of working *even if later some clients are in different time zones*.

Ultimately, [`DateTime` is a bit of a pain to work with clearly and reliably](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).